# Which PHP $_SERVER variables can be reliably used for a session fingerprint?

Tags: php, security, session

I'd like to make a way to have a session fingerprint for more secure sessions. I saw an example that used

```
$fingerpring = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

This seems reasonable, except for inconvenience to users whose ip address might change during a session.

I looked through [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) and saw a few more things that could be used. I want to add security, but also minimize inconvenience to the users. Is there anything wrong with what I came up with?

```
$fingerprint = sha1(
    $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'].
    $_SERVER['HTTP_CONNECTION'].
    substr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], 0, 5).
    $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
);
```

Will any of these $_SERVER variables change during a session and cause a user to be 'kicked off' (other than a rare ip address change)? Are there any other things I could add to the list?

Edit: I already use https and Slim's Csrf Guard.

Comment: Well, all of those values can be freely manipulated by the client. So also by some potential attacker. So you have gained no security, but a false sense for such.

Comment: But that's the whole point, isn't it @arkascha? If the data is changed then the session is no longer valid.

Comment: I'm aiming to *add* security, not perfect it. So, will this approach make it more difficult for an attacker?

Comment: @Andrew No, it is not. A potential attacker might be able to mimic all those values. So there is no additional protection against session hijacking or such thing. But if that does not really add any security, then it is a false hope that is created.

Comment: If you want to add security, use HTTPS. This is real security. `sha1()` btw is considered weak and not secure.

Comment: The session ID itself is the fingerprint ... aside from adding IP address restrictions, you can't add any meaningful security on top of it.

Comment: If you want to add even more security, use oauth2 or  2factor auth like Google's authenticator.

Comment: @Narf: _"The session ID itself is the fingerprint"_ - not with the default PHP session mechanism though? That uses just a random value AFAIK, and does not use any additional client data in the id creation.

Comment: @DanFromGermany "sha1 is insecure"… Yes, but it hardly makes any difference in this case. The attack would be to find values which hash to the same value… nobody would go through this trouble if the simpler attack is to use the original headers to begin with.

Comment: @CBroe That *is* the security. The session id itself, which is a *random value* nobody can *guess*, is the fingerprint and thereby the security mechanism.

Comment: @deceze well if it is random, then I would not call it a fingerprint.

Comment: @DanFromGermany "oauth2 or 2fa"… Yes, but that only concerns the login itself. The question here is how to strengthen the session token *post-login*.

Comment: @CBroe It's a "print" that the server attached to the client, and can henceforth use to identify the client uniquely. No, it does not use any features the client had itself, but it still works the same way.

Comment: @billy Before you talk about strengthening anything, lay out an *attack scenario* you're trying to defend against. What doesn't HTTPS + random session id cover that you're concerned about? To what degree are you able/willing to inconvenience your users to buy more security?

Comment: @deceze ok, matter of opinion/terminology then. In my understanding, a "fingerprint" always involved using actual client characteristics to "seed" the random value; if it is purely random without any such input data, then to me it is just that, a random id.

Comment: @CBroe Fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using HTTPS then one of the fundamental principle security improvements you can take is to add / set this line in your PHP.ini file:

```
 session.cookie_secure=1
```

As Deceze corrected - *This sets the secure flag on the cookie which prevents the browser from ever submitting the cookie over an unsecured connection. The cookie is still plaintext (over encrypted HTTPS).*

There are some other PHP.ini settings you can also use to improve Session security :

```
session.cookie_httponly=1
session.save_path=/setyourownpathhere/
session.use_only_cookies=1
session.entropy_file=/dev/urandom
session.hash_function=whirlpool
```

These values will further reduce the chances of your session id values being hijacked. The id value of the session is itself the "fingerprint" for the session user.

Comment: *"This makes the sesson cookie use encryption within the cookie"* – wrong. It sets the `secure` flag on the cookie which prevents the browser from ever submitting the cookie over an unsecured connection. The cookie is still plaintext (over encrypted HTTPS).

Comment: What's the point of the random value in the session? Where/when/how would you compare this to anything and for what purpose?

Comment: @deceze It would be that on a situation where the cookie id is used by another agent, then this is a second level check that both parts (cookie id and content value) correlate.

Comment: You'll need to explain in detail how that value is supposed to be used; right now it sounds like nonsense. If someone can hijack the session id to pose as the user, then their session will also contain that random value… Now what?

Comment: You do as ever, make sense. my original aim was simply to promote using the best session settings in php, but OP was keen on fingerprinting within the session so I rather added that aspect in as a secondary, not-well-thought-out additional. And somehow I was sure secure_cookie actually encrypted the cookie data.....